# drag and drop does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, html

The following drag and drop JavaScript works in Firefox, but not in IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>t</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
       .mover { 
           width:60px; height:4em; line-height:4em; margin:10px; padding:5px;
           float:left; background:#ffff99; border:1px dotted #333333; text-align:center;
        } 
    </style> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function dragWord(dragEvent) {
        dragEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", dragEvent.target.textContent + "|" + dragEvent.target.parentNode.id);
    }
    function dropWord(dropEvent) {
        var dropData = dropEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/html"); var dropItems = dropData.split("|");
        var prevElem = document.getElementById(dropItems[1]);
        prevElem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].textContent = dropEvent.target.textContent;
        dropEvent.target.textContent = dropItems[0]; dropEvent.preventDefault();
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div><em>Move the words around to make a sentence.</em></div> 
    <form>
        <div id="box1" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)"> 
            <a href="#" class="mover" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)" >page</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any clues as to why this does not work in IE? The problem is in the drag and drop function. I tried to replace the div with a href=# but that does not work.

Comment: I edited your question a little (mostly indenting code), and noticed your original code had some errors: an extra right brace (`}`) at the end of your `<script>` and extra `</div>` and `</form>` closing tags at the end of your `<html>`. I removed the errors; does your code work now?

Comment: for IE lacking `preventDefault` you can use `return false`

Comment: fun fact, IE's supported drag and drop longer than any other browser (since IE5.5 at the very least, possibly earlier). However, the APIs have changed, so depending on the IE you use, not all JS calls are supported. turn on F12 dev tools and look at the errors while you run this code. Also look up how to do drag and drop cross-browser on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/